# Updating existing entry

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to make a page which retrieves the name of the owner and giving me an option to enter my comments of his action. Sending the comments with timestamp of the appropriate selected person.

I can retrieve the 'owner' name in viewing format but I'm having problem when submitting my comments as it updates all the columns of 'comments', rather than to add it only to the selected entry (probably an'id' issue) field and timestamp doesn't capture properly, it adds a new row with blank fields but with timestamp value.

This is what I have so far:

```
<?php
function renderForm($id, $owner, $attendance, $comments, $log, $error)
{
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Log</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if ($error != '')
{
echo '<div style="padding:4px; border:1px solid red; color:red;">'.$error.'</div>';
}
?>
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"/>
<div>
<strong>OWNER: </strong><?php echo $owner; ?><br/><br/>

<strong>ATTENDANCE: </strong><select name="attendance" id="attendance">
            <option value=""><?php echo $status; ?></option>
            <option value = "Present">Ongoing</option>   
            <option value = "Absent">Closed</option>   
    </select><br/><br/>

<div style="position: absolute; top: 200px; left: 300px; width: 210px; height: 125px;">
<strong>COMMENTS: </strong><br/>
<?php 
// connect to the database
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM arc.log WHERE attendance IN ('Present', 'Absent')", MYSQLI_USE_RESULT)
    or die(mysql_error());
echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";
echo "<font color=\"white\"><tr><th>TIMESTAMP</th><th>COMMENTS</th></tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result )) {   
echo "<tr>";
echo '<td>' . $row['timestamp'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row['comments'] . '</td>';
echo "</tr>";
}
// close table>
echo "</table>";
?></div>

<div style="position: absolute; top: 8px; left: 700px; width: 210px; height: 125px;">
<strong>COMMENTS: </strong> <br/><textarea id="comments" name="comments" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea></div>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php
}
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
if (is_numeric($_POST['id']))
{
$comments = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['comments']);
$timestamp_history = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
if ($comments == '')
{
$error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';
renderForm($remarks, $error);
}
else
{
mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE arc.log SET comments='$comments'")
or die(mysql_error());
$query = "INSERT INTO `ticket`(`timestamp`) VALUES ('$timestamp')";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
}
}
else
{
echo 'Error1';
}
}
else
{
if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] > 0)
{
$id = $_GET['id'];
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM arc.log WHERE id=$id")
or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
if($row)
{
$owner = $row['owner'];
$attendance = $row['attendance'];
$comments = $row['comments'];
renderForm($id, $owner, $attendance, $comments, '');
}
else
// if no match, display result
{
echo "No results!";
}
}
else
{
echo 'Error2';
}
}
?>
```

MySQL:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UPDATE arc.log SET comments='$comments' WHERE id = $_POST['id']`

Note that you should escape the POST parameter, and not blindly copy this.

For the timestamp issue. If you don't want to insert a new record, but instead update an existing one, use `UPDATE` and not `INSERT`.

Answer (score 0):

--it updates all the columns of 'comments'-- must be corrected by replacing

```
 mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE arc.log SET comments='$comments'"); by 
 $id = $_POST['id']; 
 mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE arc.log SET comments='".$comments."',log.timestamp = '".$timestamp_history."'  where id=$id ");
```

and if the type of the colums timestamp is timestamp you must convert datetime to timestamp as below for being captured :
you must add after this line

```
$timestamp_history = date("Y-m-d h:i:s"); 
$timestamp_history =  strtotime($timestamp_history);
```